# Reform to a new json

Tags: python, arrays, json

all, I am trying to convert the JSON data from airtable to a different form in a new JSON, however I am stuck. Here is that JSON I got from airtable:

```
dataset = {"records": [{"id": "recVqe2l15WKanDS1", "fields": {"confirm": "2", "state": "MA\n", "time": "2019-01-01", "predict": "2"}, "createdTime": "2020-09-19T01:53:47.000Z"}, 
{"id": "rechRMD3sKzsweZO8", "fields": {"confirm": "1", "state": "MA\n", "time": "2019-01-01", "predict": "1"}, "createdTime": "2020-09-19T01:53:47.000Z"}, 
{"id": "recnO0uTnz3LmJNGF", "fields": {"confirm": "3", "state": "MA\n", "time": "2019-01-01", "predict": "3"}, "createdTime": "2020-09-19T01:53:47.000Z"}]}
```

The only thing I need is the information in each`"fields"` and the key of `"state"`. So that it will look like:

```
{
    MA:[{"confirm": "2", "time": "2019-01-01", "predict": "2"},
    {"confirm": "1", "time": "2019-01-01", "predict": "1"},
    {"confirm": "3",  "time": "2019-01-01", "predict": "3"}
    ....(there could be more state data like this)
}
```

In this case, I first removed the `state:MA\n`from the original data and move it to the front  with colon. Here is what I've tried so far

```
records = dataset['records']
for i in records:
    fields = i['fields']
    state = i['fields'].get('state')
    
print(state)
```

And the output will be like:

```
MA
MA
MA
```

And I am able to get the fields data like this:

```
records = dataset['records']
for i in records:
    fields = i['fields']
    print(fields)
```

which looks like this:

```
{'confirm': '2', 'state': 'MA\n', 'time': '2019-01-01', 'predict': '2'}
{'confirm': '1', 'state': 'MA\n', 'time': '2019-01-01', 'predict': '1'}
{'confirm': '3', 'state': 'MA\n', 'time': '2019-01-01', 'predict': '3'}
```

I am just wondering how do I reform them so that it can look like the data I want.(By using python)
Thank you very much for your helps!! I really appreciate it.

Comment: What exactly do you want as an output is a bit confusing ...

Comment: `JSON` is a language-independent *string representation* of a data structure. This question has nothing to do with `JSON`; what you have is a `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a `dict` with the data you want while iterating over the `dataset`:

```
results = {}

for record in dataset["records"]:
    # extract and remove state
    state = record["fields"].pop("state").strip()

    if not state in results: # new state found
        results[state] = []

    # append data to corresponding state
    results[state].append(record["fields"])
```

Can be done a bit shorter, when we use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

results = defaultdict(list)

for record in dataset["records"]:
    results[record["fields"].pop("state").strip()].append(record["fields"])
```

Output:

```
{'MA': [{'confirm': '2', 'time': '2019-01-01', 'predict': '2'},
  {'confirm': '1', 'time': '2019-01-01', 'predict': '1'},
  {'confirm': '3', 'time': '2019-01-01', 'predict': '3'}]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I also need to use pip to install the collections right?

Comment: The collections module is part of the standard library. It's already included in a normal python installation. @FrankLiu

Comment: Cool thanks, so if there are more states_name in the data, I could use the similar way to separate them in different lists?

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the below code too:

```
dataset = {"records":[{"id":"recVqe2l15WKanDS1","fields":{"confirm":"2","state":"MA\n","time":"2019-01-01","predict":"2"},"createdTime":"2020-09-19T01:53:47.000Z"},{"id":"rechRMD3sKzsweZO8","fields":{"confirm":"1","state":"MA\n","time":"2019-01-01","predict":"1"},"createdTime":"2020-09-19T01:53:47.000Z"},{"id":"recnO0uTnz3LmJNGF","fields":{"confirm":"3","state":"MA\n","time":"2019-01-01","predict":"3"},"createdTime":"2020-09-19T01:53:47.000Z"},{"id":"rechRMD3sKzsweZO8","fields":{"confirm":"1","state":"CD\n","time":"2019-01-01","predict":"1"},"createdTime":"2020-09-19T01:53:47.000Z"},{"id":"rechRMD3sKzsweZO8","fields":{"confirm":"1","state":"CD\n","time":"2019-01-01","predict":"1"},"createdTime":"2020-09-19T01:53:47.000Z"},{"id":"rechRMD3sKzsweZO8","fields":{"confirm":"1","state":"QW\n","time":"2019-01-01","predict":"1"},"createdTime":"2020-09-19T01:53:47.000Z"}]}


state_dict = {}
for data in dataset['records']:
    state = data['fields'].pop('state')
    state_dict.update(
        {
            state: state_dict.get(state, [])
        }
    )
    state_dict[state].append(data['fields'])
print(state_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'MA\n': [{'confirm': '2', 'time': '2019-01-01', 'predict': '2'}, {'confirm': '1', 'time': '2019-01-01', 'predict': '1'}, {'confirm': '3', 'time': '2019-01-01', 'predict': '3'}], 'CD\n': [{'confirm': '1', 'time': '2019-01-01', 'predict': '1'}, {'confirm': '1', 'time': '2019-01-01', 'predict': '1'}], 'QW\n': [{'confirm': '1', 'time': '2019-01-01', 'predict': '1'}]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've never thought of using a pop and update method.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the desired output:

```
new_format = {'MA': [{
    'confirm': record['fields']['confirm'],
    'time': record['fields']['time'],
    'predict': record['fields']['predict']
    } for record in dataset["records"]]}
```